# Calling 2 buttons functions in the same form PHP

Tags: javascript, php, buttonclick

I implemented a page with 2 buttons which call 2 different functions on their button clicks. But the any of the buttons are not working. They are just reload the same page. I'll put my code down below.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal"  id="add_product_form" method="post">
<script>
    function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('add_product_form').action = action;
        document.getElementById('add_product_form').submit();
    }
</script>



 <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="submit" onclick="return check_add_to_cart();" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg add-to-cart btn-block" value="Add To Cart">
<input type="submit" onclick=onclick="return check_add_to_quote();" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg add-to-quote btn-block" value="Add To quote">
        </div>
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you! Add_to_cart function which is mentioned above the page.

```
function check_add_to_cart(){
  var quantity = jQuery('#quantity').val();
  var data = jQuery('#add_product_form').serialize();
  if(jQuery.isNumeric(quantity) && quantity > 0){
    return true
  } else if(quantity < 1) {
    jQuery('#cart_error').html('<?=display_error_str("Quantity must be greater than 0.");?>');
    return false;
  }else {
    jQuery('#cart_error').html('<?=display_error_str("Quantity must be a number.");?>');
    return false;
  }

  function check_add_to_quote(){
    var quantity = jQuery('#quantity').val();
    var data = jQuery('#add_product_form').serialize();
    if(jQuery.isNumeric(quantity) && quantity > 0){
      return true
    } else if(quantity < 1) {
      jQuery('#cart_error').html('<?=display_error_str("Quantity must be greater than 0.");?>');
      return false;
    }else {
      jQuery('#cart_error').html('<?=display_error_str("Quantity must be a number.");?>');
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `check_add_to_cart` and `check_add_to_quote` functions defined?

Comment: Read my question in comment again where functions are **defined**?

Comment: I updated the question. Have a look. Thanks!  @B. Desai

Answer (score 0):

You can do following. Change type`submit` to `button` And as you already have `submitForm()` method. Call this method when you want to return true.

Change

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return check_add_to_cart();" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg add-to-cart btn-block" value="Add To Cart">
<input type="submit" onclick=onclick="return check_add_to_quote();" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg add-to-quote btn-block" value="Add To quote">
```

To

```
<input type="button" onclick="return check_add_to_cart();" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg add-to-cart btn-block" value="Add To Cart">
<input type="button" onclick=onclick="return check_add_to_quote();" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg add-to-quote btn-block" value="Add To quote">
```

And change your js functions to:

```
function check_add_to_cart(){
  var quantity = jQuery('#quantity').val();
  var data = jQuery('#add_product_form').serialize();
  if(jQuery.isNumeric(quantity) && quantity > 0){
    //return true
     submitForm(""); //you can pass action in this if you want other page
  } else if(quantity < 1) {
    jQuery('#cart_error').html('<?=display_error_str("Quantity must be greater than 0.");?>');
    return false;
  }else {
    jQuery('#cart_error').html('<?=display_error_str("Quantity must be a number.");?>');
    return false;
  }

  function check_add_to_quote(){
    var quantity = jQuery('#quantity').val();
    var data = jQuery('#add_product_form').serialize();
    if(jQuery.isNumeric(quantity) && quantity > 0){
      //return true
       submitForm(""); //you can pass action in this if you want other page
    } else if(quantity < 1) {
      jQuery('#cart_error').html('<?=display_error_str("Quantity must be greater than 0.");?>');
      return false;
    }else {
      jQuery('#cart_error').html('<?=display_error_str("Quantity must be a number.");?>');
      return false;
    }
}
```

And remove `submitForm()` definition between **html** and add it to **script block**